# Write a property in a property file without breaking the window path in a file

Tags: java, properties, path, window

I have property file in windows containing a absolute file path like following:

```
[PRAXIS]
PVS=CDP_Z1
PXID=94773

[SENDEN]
PVS=CDP_Z1
DATEI=C:\imex_workspace\1535_1297160840340.1247
VERSION=2.5

[STATUS]
ERRORLEVEL=0
ERRORTEXT=
READY=0
```

This A file contains a file path of B file. I would like to use Java Properties class to write the READY property to 1, the others remain the same.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
String upload = "a.ini";
p.load(new FileInputStream(upload));
if(p.get("READY") != null && "0".equals(p.get("READY")))
{
  p.setProperty("READY","1");
  p.store(new FileOutputStream(new File(upload)),null);
}
```

somehow the file path inside a.ini is broken after a.ini has been updated.
Someone help to find out the best way to write a property inside a file (might not be ini,could be txt file).

Comment: how is the file/path broken?

Comment: ini files and properties files don't have the same format. Don't try to generate ini files with Properties: it won't work.

Comment: #Sat Feb 02 14:44:03 CET 2013
[SENDEN]=
DATEI=C\:imex_workspace1535_1297160840340.1247
READY=1
[STATUS]=
ERRORTEXT=
[PRAXIS]=
ERRORLEVEL=0
PVS=CDP_Z1
PXID=94773
VERSION=2.5

Comment: The problem is the file format could be anything. It could be txt file. Is there any better class than properties to write the "READY" to 1

Comment: It's impossible to modify a file without knowing its format, and hope it's still valid after the modification. Your problem doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind your problem is that for Java Properties files, the backslash character is used as [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats) as in C or in Java language.

This file you posted in your question, is not a valid Java properties file, it's a Windows INI file. Windows INI file differ from Java properties file since they have "sections" (praxis senden status in your example), and also because paths are specified in DOS format, which means that backslash (`\`) is used as path separator. In Java path separator can be used as backslash (`\`)in Windows, but most commonly the unix slash is preferred (`/`). The thing is that, if you want to use the backslash you need to "escape" it, so your path should be specified with double backslashes:

```
DATEI=C:\\imex_workspace\\1535_1297160840340.1247
```

or otherwise:

```
DATEI=C:/imex_workspace/1535_1297160840340.1247
```

in this way the path is compatible with the Java properties files format. But this can have side effects with the Windows application that uses this .ini file.

To solve this problem, I think you'd better to use an appropriate library to deal with Windows `.ini` configuration files, which will guarantee to cover this case, but also other possibilities that you may not have considered, since Java properties files follow a different specification than the Windows `.ini` format.

Here you find a couple of libraries you may want to consider:

- [Ini4J](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)
- [JIniFile](https://github.com/SubZane/JIniFile)